# How to determine Laravel Projects running in Homestead

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, homestead

So I have two laravel projects running in homestead. Everything's running well in my PC where the projects are located. But in the other computer in a network, it won't work.

**Here's my Homestead.yaml:**

---

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:\Users\Lekz\development\projects\laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: laravel.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/acctg_pending2/public
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/test/public

databases:
    - addessa_acctg_pending
    - testdb

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

**And my hosts file:**

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

# redirecting this is just a bad idea 127.0.0.1       localhost
# redirecting this is just a bad idea 127.0.0.1       localhost
# redirecting this is just a bad idea 127.0.0.1       localhost
# redirecting this is just a bad idea 127.0.0.1       localhost
# redirecting this is just a bad idea 127.0.0.1       localhost
#127.0.0.1      localhost
192.168.10.10   laravel.dev
192.168.10.10   homestead.app
```

I can run the two projects without a problem in my PC. But When I tend to run those projects in other computer in a network it won't work. I can only run the second project typing `192.168.1._:8000 (my PC's IP)`.

How can I determine the projects in other computer in a network when it has the same IP? Like in my hosts file:

```
192.168.10.10   laravel.dev
192.168.10.10   homestead.app
```

Comment: Are you create virtual site in /var/apache2/sites-available/... or something like this?

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn, what do you mean? Maybe not, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Somethings like https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts - In step four.

Comment: Where can I find apache2 when running homestead? BTW I'm working with Windows.

Comment: Sorry I miss understand you using Homestead.

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn, yeah I'm using Homestead. And it's my first time using it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124754/discussion-between-lekz-flores-and-qunh-nguyn).

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Are you getting an error?

Comment: No errors, it's just don't work. When I type in the browser `laravel.dev` and `homestead.app` it says `Problem loading page`. But when I try to type in the IP of the machine who runs the VirtualBox Machine with port 8000  it just run the second project. So how can I determine those two projects if they served with the same IP? Any idea sir? I want to run these projects with Homestead not in apache.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a virtual machine with an assigned IP address 192.168.10.10

The machine running the Homestead VM will access it through that IP address.

Your hosts file is an alias to that IP address of the VM Homestead.

..

If someone then takes the vagrantFile of your instance they can spin up their Homestead (aka Vagrant) instance with the VM's details.

The new machine using the vagrantFile will need to have their host file edited to match the same IP address as listed out in their Homestead/Vagrant.yaml file.

If you wanted to serve the laravel instance through your local machines ip address using a port you can do so using the

```
php artisan serve
```

command from the projects root directory. However, note additional dependencies for sql and composer may be need.

Comment: I already set the hosts file in the other computer but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does the other(computer code is being cloned onto) computer have vagrant/Homestead and virtualBox installed?

Comment: No, is it necessary?

Comment: Yes they are, those are the base for the import.

Comment: Oh I see. Is there any workaround? Like running it in apache and other machines just have to edit the hosts file. If that's the case in Homestead, every machine in a network have to have a vagrant/Homestead and vm installed right?

Comment: correct, every machine would need the vm on it to host the environment.